# Error in SQL Syntax using Any(x => c.Contains(x))

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to search from a client table using entity framework. It works when running it locally but when I uploaded it on the server I got the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%mark%)' at line 23

This is the code I'm using:

```
string[] searchCriteria = search.Split(' ');

var clients = from c in context.client
          where searchCriteria.Any(x => c.name.Contains(x)) ||
          searchCriteria.Any(x => c.surname.Contains(x)) ||
          searchCriteria.Any(x => c.email.Contains(x)) ||
          searchCriteria.Any(x => c.mobile.Contains(x)) ||
          searchCriteria.Any(x => c.code.Contains(x)) ||
          searchCriteria.Any(x => c.company.Contains(x))
          select c;
```

As requested, the SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`email`, 
`Extent1`.`password`, 
`Extent1`.`name`, 
`Extent1`.`surname`, 
`Extent1`.`address1`, 
`Extent1`.`address2`, 
`Extent1`.`cityid`, 
`Extent1`.`deliveryaddress1`, 
`Extent1`.`deliveryaddress2`, 
`Extent1`.`deliverycityid`, 
`Extent1`.`phone`, 
`Extent1`.`mobile`, 
`Extent1`.`code`, 
`Extent1`.`vat`, 
`Extent1`.`company`
FROM `client` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (((((EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`name` LIKE '%mark%')) OR (EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable2`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`surname` LIKE '%mark%'))) OR (EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable3`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`email` LIKE '%mark%'))) OR (EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable4`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`mobile` LIKE '%mark%'))) OR (EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable5`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`code` LIKE '%mark%'))) OR (EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable6`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`company` LIKE '%mark%'))
```

I'd like to also point out, that when I run this directly in the database, it works fine.

Comment: Did you update to the latest MySQL Connector for .NET?

Comment: What does the SQL statement look like? A bug in the connector is probably creating bad SQL. In fact, that error looks very suspicious - if the connector uses parameterized queries, the argument to `LIKE` should never appear inside the query

Comment: Yes I have the latest MySQL Connector (6.9.8).